# Classify between files and fodler in S3 bucket -Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Note:** I know that amazon buckets do not have the concept of folder, but im using that term for the sake of simplicity

So iam trying to list files in my s3 bucket using `boto`. Its fairly simple using:

```
for files in bucket.list():
            print files.name
```

Which lists an output like this

```
file1
file2
file3
test_folder/file4
test_folder/file5
```

How do i classify between files and folders here? i just want to list the files and then only the folder `test_folder` once.

Looking for something like this:

```
File:s
    file1
    file2
    file3
Folders:
    test_folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to suppress the "Files:" output for all files which are contained in folders (i.e. those with a '/' character in their filename), and then print out the distinct folder names separately at the end. If so, how about something like this:

```py
print "Files: "
folders = set()
for files in bucket.list():
  if '/' not in files.name:
    print "\t", files.name
  else:
    folders.add(files.name[:files.name.rfind('/')])

print "Folders: "
for folder in folders:
  print "\t", folder
```

Comment: This solution doesnt work when I put in the path as `test_folder/test_folder1` and so on.

Comment: Why not? What output do you get when dealing with such nested folders, and what output do you expect?

Comment: The files are named as `path/to/file/filename.txt` if they are located deep inside multiple folders. So they skipped over when when i user your `if` statement because we only search for `if '/' not in file:`